# Suppress Non-nullable property on DatabaseGenerated column

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

I have the following abstract class:

```
public abstract class Entity<TKey> 
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public TKey Id { get; set; }
}
```

I want to use this class as a base class for all my Entity Framework entity classes.

All is good except I have a warning that I want to suppress.

I have a nullable reference types enabled and I receive the following warning:

> Warning CS8618
> Non-nullable property 'Id' must contain a non-null value when exiting constructor. Consider declaring the property as nullable.

With other properties where I have this warning, I've been able to add the constructor as suggested. But as this is going to be an autogenerated value on the database I can't really do that.

I have some classes that use an Int as the key and others that use string so I can't add a struct constraint on the generic TKey.

So how can I suppress this warning?

Comment: If the key can be string then it can't have an Identity specification. It seems to me that database-generated key values are hard to combine with a generic key type anyway.

Comment: You can have both int and guid as identity specification, so using a generic key could be very practical if you have a combination in your database.

Answer (score 2):

To suppress warnings for a generic type, use the `default!` syntax:

```
public abstract class Entity<TKey>
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public TKey Id { get; set; } = default!; // no more CS8618
}
```